# Trouble with automating clicks of radio buttons on CL with iMacros

Tags: automation, imacros, craigslist

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

I'm loving the possibilities and having fun learning some automation via iMacros, however, I've run into an issue and I don't see answers specific to this issue in this forum nor the iMacros forums yet.  I'm hoping someone here may understand this specific problem.  It shouldn't be difficult, but I'm really struggling.

I have a series of iMacros 'scripts' that I run manually 5-6 times per day to post craigslist ads for buying real estate. I do this in the 'housing wanted' section for 'real estate wanted'... My scripts aren't complicated, but I cannot seem to automate the two screens where I need to select a radio button from a choice of options such as on the next two page links:

```
https://post.craigslist.org/k/Ghd9_C8m5 ... R1m?s=type
```

and

/* deleted second link because this forum does not allow newbies to submit two links in a post */

...On the first link I want to select 'housing wanted' and on the second link I want to select 'real estate wanted'. But the selection of these radio buttons does not record when I'm recording the macro in iMacros? Everything else records just fine. The iMacros extension for Chrome has really saved me a good bit of time simply on the form filling parts, however, if I could just finally automate those last two clicks, it would really help out a lot. I even think I read somewhere that you can then set iMacros to run the scripts on a schedule which would be even more helpful, but I'll have to learn that later.

One thing to note is that when clicking these radio buttons on those craigslist pages, they advance to the next page WITHOUT hitting the [continue] button as it would seem you should need to do.

Below is my iMacros script.

```
VERSION BUILD=8070701 RECORDER=CR
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=chrome://newtab/
URL GOTO=http://jacksonville.craigslist.org/

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:my<SP>account
WAIT SECONDS=2
SET !ENCRYPTION STOREDKEY

'------login stuff deleted-------
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=NAME:login ATTR=TXT:
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:login ATTR=TXT:Log<SP>In
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:craigslist
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:housing<SP>wanted
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:post
WAIT SECONDS=2
PAUSE
```

------ this pause is where I step in to manually select the buttons on the two pages where I cannot select the radio buttons.--------

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=ID:contact_phone_ok CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=ID:contact_text_ok CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=ID:contact_phone CONTENT=xxx-xxx-xxxx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=ID:contact_name CONTENT=XXX
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=ID:PostingTitle CONTENT=XXX
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=ID:GeographicArea CONTENT=XXX
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=ID:postal_code CONTENT=XXX
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=ID:PostingBody CONTENT=XXX
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=ID:oc CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:postingForm ATTR=NAME:go
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found it was caused by noscript plugin. Problem was resolved once I disabled noscript. Now I would like to find a way how these two (imacros and noscript) can live together... :)